# Does consenting the usage of tracking Cookies also cover tracking Pixels under GDPR?

Tags: gdpr, cookies

Last December [Stack Overflow announced a change to the network advertisement policies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395389/update-to-our-advertising-guidelines).

> “Retargeting pixels are <strike>not allowed on any campaign.</strike> allowed for a limited number of vetted and pre-approved Programmatic partners.”

The change introduced the use of Retargeting ***pixels*** on the network.

Later an user [asked if the change invalidates previous consent given on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395431/will-the-tracking-pixels-replace-the-existing-advertiser-tracking):

> Will this change invalidate the consent granted by existing users, requiring them to re-consent?
> Since you're changing what you're asking permission for, it should.

Sasha, a staff member replied with the following (emphasis mine):

> The change in the advertising guidelines announced on December 12th does not have any effect on the consent that users have given in their cookie settings because nothing in the cookie settings modal has been altered. **The cookie consent modal already included a toggle for consenting to targeting cookies, and the consent that users have issued on that is still valid**

Now, it is my understanding that a tracking cookie and a tracking pixel are not the same thing. While the pixel can also involve a cookie the former will also use javascript to perform additional tracking that goes beyond the capabilities of a regular cookie. At the very best a standard cookie should stop to work once deleted while a pixel implies a level of tracking that it is not dependent on a file on the user device.

The current **cookie** consent window for the network looks like this:

[image: network tracking cookies consents setting]

Only cookies are specifically mentioned.

It is my understanding in order to be valid, consent for personal data usage has to be given in a way that clearly states the purpose and how the data is collected.

I am not a lawyer but [Article 7](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02016R0679-20160504) specifically seems to point in this direction:

> Article 7
>
> Conditions for consent
>
> 1. Where processing is based on consent, the controller shall be able to demonstrate that the data subject has consented to processing
>    of his or her personal data.
> 2. If the data subject's consent is given in the context of a written declaration which also concerns other matters, the request for
>    consent shall be presented in a manner which is clearly
>    distinguishable from the other matters, in an intelligible and easily
>    accessible form, using clear and plain language. Any part of such a
>    declaration which constitutes an infringement of this Regulation shall
>    not be binding.

I am therefore curious. Is Sasha statement about "not requiring a new consent" correct or the inclusion of a new form of tracking would require a new specific consent since it does not appear covered by the previous one in a way that a regular, non technical user would understand (it is still tracking, but not the same type of tracking)?

Bonus question: would the answer be different if the consent was made more generic from the start, for example:

> **Targeted Advertisement
>
> Cookies and other tracking technologies** are used to make advertising messages more relevant to you and may be set through our site by us or by our advertising partners. They may be used to build a profile of your interests and show you relevant advertising on our site or on other sites. They do not store directly personal information, but are based on uniquely identifying your browser and internet device.

---

**UPDATE**
In a comment amon suggested to look at the ePrivacy Directive. I skimmed thru and found an interesting article.

> (21a)
> Cookies can also be a legitimate and useful tool, for example,
> in assessing the effectiveness of a delivered information society
> service, for example of website design and advertising or by helping
> to measure the numbers of end-users visiting a website, certain pages
> of a website or the number of end-users of an application. This is not
> the case, however, **regarding cookies and similar identifiers used to
> determine the nature of who is using the site, which always require
> the consent of the end-user.**

This obviously means that tracking pixels should require consent. The wording seems also to indicate that they require "explicit" consent, so the consent to "tracking cookies" should not provide consent to "javascript based tracking". Is this right?

Comment: Consent is defined by the GDPR, but the ePrivacy Directive ("cookie law") might be more relevant. It doesn't specifically discuss cookies, but instead any access or storage of information on the user's device. Data protection authorities have long held that tracking pixels also fall under this law, [most recently the EDPB](https://edpb.europa.eu/our-work-tools/documents/public-consultations/2023/guidelines-22023-technical-scope-art-53-eprivacy_en) (see section 3.1). The *Fashion ID* case clarifies that SE is responsible for having a suitable GDPR legal basis for tracking pixels, e.g. consent.

Comment: @amon thanks for the information. Do you by chance have any insight about the requirements for user consents to be considered valid? As you may have guessed, I was mainly trying to determine if the current form of the consent (very specifically focused on "cookies") may be considered a wild char consent for other related tracking technologies.

Comment: Consent is specific to a *purpose*, not necessarily specific to the means through which the purpose is achieved. There is an argument that this change is compliant, and shouldering the remaining risk can definitely be a good business decision. If you're interested in details on consent, consider the [EDPB Guidelines 05/2020 (PDF)](https://edpb.europa.eu/our-work-tools/our-documents/guidelines/guidelines-052020-consent-under-regulation-2016679_en) and/or the [UK ICO guidance on consent](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/uk-gdpr-guidance-and-resources/lawful-basis/consent/).

Comment: @amon True, I got the same idea too. But the issue is that in this case the consent is given from a form that is written to be specific to a mean - cookies. This made me wonder if the consent can be considered flawed (and thus invalid?) since it misrepresent the ways the purpose is achieved. Basically: does the misrepresentation (or incomplete presentation) of the means violate the principle of  giving a clear and understandable presentation of the purpose?

Comment: I think that is a great question, but one that could be argued either way. I'm not aware of any EU/UK cases or guidance that would shed light on this question. Personally, I think SE is being user-hostile and sneaky (as usual), but I'm not convinced it's actually illegal. While I think means-specific consent would be binding, the means here seem so similar that they might very well be compatible. The big lie in the screenshotted consent message isn't cookie vs pixel, but that these tracking means "do not store directly identifying information" which is rather misleading.